# Using VBA for Excel: Pulling data from ODBC SQL, how do use a value of "one year before today"?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, odbc

I recorded a macro that works fine, but I want to use a dynamic date so I don't have to enter it every time. I want to use the `WHERE` statement to pull records between today and one year prior to today. I had to submit specific date ranges when I recorded the macro, and I want to replace the timestamp with something dynamic, but `CURRENT_DATE` didn't work (syntax error) and `TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_YEAR, -1, CURRENT_DATE)` didn't work (syntax error). The macro recorded as such:

```vb
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "ODBC;DRIVER={Centura SQLBase 3.5 32-bit Driver -NT & Win95};UID=ODBC;;DB=CAM32;SRVR=01CAM001A" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT SALES_LOG_DETAIL.STORE_NUMBER, SALES_LOG_DETAIL.DATE_TIME, SALES_LOG_DETAIL.ITEM_NUMBER, SALES_LOG_DETAIL.QUANTITY, SALES_LOG_DETAIL.PRICE_PAID" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM SYSADM.SALES_LOG_DETAIL SALES_LOG_DETAIL" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "W" _
        , _
        "HERE (SALES_LOG_DETAIL.STORE_NUMBER>=2 And SALES_LOG_DETAIL.STORE_NUMBER<=11) AND (SALES_LOG_DETAIL.DATE_TIME>={ts '2017-09-11 00:00:00'} And SALES_LOG_DETAIL.DATE_TIME<={ts '2018-09-11 00:00:00'})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "O" _
        , "RDER BY SALES_LOG_DETAIL.STORE_NUMBER, SALES_LOG_DETAIL.ITEM_NUMBER")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = True
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Sales_Log_All_Stores"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

I have no idea why it formats it that way, but when I try to change it I get errors.
How do I change that timestamp code to something that will pull the current date and also look back one year?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 ?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS as SQL dialects especially for time functions differ.

Comment: @Parfait What does that mean? Tag it in my stackoverflow comment? Or something in the code?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thank you for that link. I tried DATEADD but I received a "Unrecognized function" error in MS Query.

Comment: https://support.guptatechnologies.com/Docs/SQLBase/sqlbase901sqllang.pdf

Comment: `....(SALES_LOG_DETAIL.DATE_TIME>={ts '" & year(date)-1 & "-09-11 00:00:00'}……`